# Why won't my frame pack python3 tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I run the code below I do not get an error but the bottom frame doesn't appear in the window please can you tell me why and how I can make it appear (using the pack method NOT GRID please). I am using Python 3.5.0

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")
TopFrame = Frame(root, width=1920, height=200, bg= "green")
TopFrame.pack(side=TOP)
MiddleRightFrame = Frame(root, width=1120, height=730, bg="orange")
MiddleRightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)
MiddleLeftFrame = Frame(root, width=800, height=730, bg="black")
MiddleLeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
BottomFrame = Frame(root, width=1920, height=150, bg="blue")
BottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Comment: There are a number of ways making your blue frame visible. Provide the image for the _exact_ GUI you want.

Comment: You do realize that your frames will shrink or expand soon as they contain something else, right?

Comment: Yes I am going to make the buttons the exact size of the frame I will use 8 evenly sized buttons each height 150 and width 240

Comment: I think you're forcing an overly direct way of producing a GUI, which needlessly complicates it all then. Where I think `place` excels over grid or pack.

Comment: This is part of course work for school I already have a large amount of it done but can not get this window to operate properly I have used pack in the rest of the code and changing it now would be too time consuming and would not allow me to finish my work before the deadline.

Comment: You can simply put pack parts in an encapsulating frame, then use grid on that frame if that's the case. The way this works is prune to many more errors IMO.

Comment: When you say "make it appear" where do you want it to appear? The way you've coded it it will appear between the left and right frames if there's room. Do you want it to appear at the very bottom of the window, spanning the whole window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using pack sides so that in the middle there is a line of nothing. One way to get around this is to create a `MiddleFrame` where pack sides are used and then just pack the other frames.

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

TopFrame = Frame(root, width=1920, height=200, bg= "green")
TopFrame.pack()

#the middle frame
MiddleFrame = Frame(root)

#pack the two middle frames into the frame created above
#the parent of the two middle frames change to become MiddleFrame instead of root
MiddleRightFrame = Frame(MiddleFrame, width=1120, height=730, bg="orange")
MiddleRightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

MiddleLeftFrame = Frame(MiddleFrame, width=800, height=730, bg="black")
MiddleLeftFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

#pack the middle frame with both frames inside it
MiddleFrame.pack()

BottomFrame = Frame(root, width=1920, height=150, bg="blue")
BottomFrame.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `MiddleLeftFrame` is 800 pixels wide.  Your `MiddleRightFrame` is 1120 pixels. 1120 + 800 = 1920. You're forcing the window to be only 1920 pixels wide, so there's no room for the blue frame.

Remove this line and your frame will appear: `root.geometry("1920x1080")`

If your intent is for it to appear at the bottom of the window, spanning the entire width of the window, then call `pack` on it before you call `pack` on the left and right sides.

Also, I strongly recommend grouping your `pack` statements together. It makes the code easier to manage in my experience (and I have a *lot* of experience!).

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

TopFrame = Frame(root, width=1920, height=200, bg= "green")
MiddleRightFrame = Frame(root, width=1120, height=730, bg="orange")
MiddleLeftFrame = Frame(root, width=800, height=730, bg="black")
BottomFrame = Frame(root, width=1920, height=150, bg="blue")

TopFrame.pack(side=TOP)
BottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
MiddleRightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)
MiddleLeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

The reason this works is due to the packer algorithm. When you place something on the left or right, it will allocate all of the remaining vertical space on that side. Thus, after you pack something on the left and right and then later pack something on the bottom, the "bottom" is the bottom of the space between the left and right, not the bottom of the window as a whole.

Here is the canonical description of how `pack` works:

http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the _why_ part of the question. Thanks for that. Does that mean when there's not enough space, the widgets are simply _not shown_?

Comment: This is incorrect (I know I could have been more clear in my question by adding an image however I could not get the image to work).
The width of both frames is 1920 and their height is 730 meaning there is still a space of width 1920 and height 350 (150 for the blue frame and 200 for the green frame).
TLDR:
The placement of the frames fits in a 1920x1080 window.
See the answer by @Carwley. That is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Nae: correct, it's possible for widgets to be invisible if there's not enough space for them, as this example shows.

Comment: @Fake: No, it's not incorrect. I can say with certainty. The way `pack` was used in this example, the frame is placed between the left and right side. Even though the frame in question was placed on the bottom, it's the bottom of the _available_ space, not the bottom of the window as a whole. As I suggested, remove the call to `geometry` and the frame will appear between the left and right sides. You didn't ask how to get it to appear at the bottom of the window,  you simply asked why it wasn't appearing.

Comment: @Fake: I've updated my answer to give a better explanation, and to show a very simple solution if your goal is for the bottom frame to be at the very bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
tkinter.mainloop()
```

so that the GUI starts waiting for events as opposed to skipping to close itself.

---

Additionally, pack uses a filling algorithm which calculates dynamically to fill the empty space. You shouldn't really be doing it like this but a simple call swap would suffice in this specific case. Call:

```
BottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

*exactly after* `TopFrame`'s pack:

```
TopFrame.pack(side=TOP)
BottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
MiddleRightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)
MiddleLeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
```